# XML date tag is non human understandably format when SMS data is backed up

Tags: xml

I have backed up my phone sms onto my laptop. It has been stored in an xml format. The date under the date tag is not in human understandable format. Kindly let me know what is the date in the date tag?
The date specified in the tag is : 1456856115780.

```
   <sms>   
     <address>'somePhoneNumber'</address>
     <body>'someMessageBody'</body>
     <date>1456856115780</date>
     <type>2</type>
   </sms>
```

Comment: May be https://currentmillis.com/ milliseconds since epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Re "not in human understandable format", that's just because you're not a geeky enough human yet :-)

If the *readable* date (assuming you can establish this from the phone itself) of whatever item you're looking for is somewhere around mid-March 2016, then it's most likely the number of milliseconds since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970 UTC).

`1456856115` seconds equates to about `46.2` years, which would place the date somewhere around that time frame (adding `1970` and `46` gives `2016`, `0.2` of a year is `73`-odd days, the `73`rd day of the year (in a leap year like `2016`) is `March 13`).